# $ABC$ is right triangle at $A$ such that $BC=2AB$, find the length $CH$ (look at picture) $\hat{AHB}$ right angle

Tags: geometry

[image]

So I found $CH=(\sqrt{3}/2)AB$ is it correct? Thanks :)

Comment: Is AH perpendicular to CB? If yes, you may consider similar triangle relation between BAC and AHC.

Comment: @nam Yes AH is peprendicular to CB

Comment: What you found is correct, though you don't say **how** you found it.

Comment: @DonAntonio I found it based on the fact that cosACH=cosACB

Comment: @DonAntonio maybe its 3/2 AB and not sqrt3/2 AB ?

Comment: Nop @Nicepic: all three straight-angle triangles are $\;30-60-90\;$ ones, so if the shortest leg (in front of the $\;30^\circ\;$ angle) is $\;x\;$, the largest leg is $\;\sqrt3\, x\;$ . From here the square root.

Comment: I don't understand how you did that based on that, @Nicepic ...

Comment: @DonAntonio $\cos(ACH)=\cos(ACB)\implies AC/BC=CH/AC\implies AC²/BC=CH\implies (AC=\sqrt{3}AB):3AB²/2AB=CH\implies (3/2)AB=CH$

Comment: You're completely right, @Nicepic: it is $\;\frac32\;$ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints (for you to understand and prove):

$$\angle C=30^\circ\;,\;\;|AC|=\sqrt3\, |AB|\implies$$

$$\frac{\sqrt3}2=\sin60^\circ=\sin B=\frac{|AH|}{|AB|}\implies |AH|=\frac{\sqrt3}2|AB|$$

Finally

$$\frac{\sqrt3}2=\cos30^\circ=\cos C=\frac{|CH|}{|AC|}\implies |CH|=\frac{\sqrt3}2|AC|=\frac{3}2|AB|$$

**Without trigonometry:**

$$\Delta AHC=\Delta BAC\implies \frac{AC}{BC}=\frac{AH}{AB}=\frac{HC}{AC}\implies$$

$$CH=AC\frac{AH}{AB}$$

But a $\;30-60-90\;$ triangle has sides in proportions $\;x\,:\,\sqrt3\,x\,:\,2x\;$ , so

$$AC=\sqrt3\,AB\;,\;\;AH=\frac{\sqrt3}2AB\implies CH=\frac32AB$$

Comment: haha thanks that was a very nice discussion with you :)

Comment: Indeed it was, @Nicepic: my pleasure.